# why the backspace does not work in mac / keyboard events

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have some backspace issues with flash application with some MAC users, I am using keyboard events.

Any tips why it does not work?

backspace is OK in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

you can try for deep linking in flex. You can read from liveDocs. Please check out there